# how to use python code output from azure pipeline as data source into power bi?

Tags: python, azure-devops, powerbi, azure-pipelines, repository

I have a python code running in my azure devops pipeline. I see the output within azure but would like to know how to get this output into a storable format and send it as data source to Power BI for visualization? #azure devops #azuredatafactory #azurepipeline #pythoncode